# Nginx, PATH_INFO, and url-rewriting: i must be missing something

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url-routing, mod-rewrite

I'm switching from Apache to Nginx/fcgi and I'm having a small issue while attempting to setup the applications rewrite rules.

The code handles routes via the use of PATH_INFO, e.g., example.com/foo/bar/ will be routed to example.com/index.php/foo/bar/

I've modified the server configuration to pass PATH_INFO:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;

      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/public$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

And the rewrite handler:

```
location / {
      root   /var/www/public;
      index  index.html index.htm index.php;

      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php/$2 break;
      }
    }
```

With '**rewrite_log on**', the url's appear to be routing properly:

```
[error]: *2 open() "/var/www/public/index.php/test" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 192.168.0.254, server: example.com, request: "GET /test HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/index.php"
```

However, it appears to be looking for the directory "test". **How can I force it to request index.php, passing '/test' to the script?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're following a poor tutorial which is severely outdated (`if (!-f`  is generally not recommended, with `try_files` offered as a better replacement). You have numerous problems:

*First* you have directives in `location /` context which should be in `server` context, so you can avoid path duplication in the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` variable.

*Secondly*, you use the `break` flag in your rewrite; this means it should not re-evaluate the location matching. This effectively makes the request never leave the `location /` block and is instead treated as a static file request.

*Thirdly*, have a look at your `location ~ \.php$ {`: Nginx matches locations against the URI and you're specifically telling Nginx to only handle URIs which end in `.php`, but if you rewrite to `index.php/test/` then it won't trigger.

*Lastly*, you're using `PATH_INFO` while you should be using `REQUEST_URI`. The difference is that to make PATH_INFO work you have to tell Nginx to pass any request with `.php` in it to PHP, and PHP has to then find the right file.

This means that you allow requests like `example.org/uploads/image.jpg/index.php` to be sent to PHP and you also allow PHP to execute the file `/uploads/image.jpg`. If a malicious user uploaded that file with PHP in it they now have arbitrary code execution on your server. **This is a very real exploit** that I have personally seen people be vulnerable to.

Please stop using randomly Googled tutorials because 90% of them are utter garbage, instead go read [the wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main). It might be a bother having to actually learn about the web server you're using, but the alternative is to have your server compromised.

Comment: Thanks Martin, aside from being a bit of a prick, that was very helpful. FWIW: PATH_INFO execution must go through a strict set of constraints before execution.

Comment: original source: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule